# Get character before and after match in string

Tags: lua

I've the a few strings and somewhere inside the string there is a `/`. Like `bis 0/5 nta`.

I'm trying to get the number on each side of the `/` and including `/` like `0/5`.

I have tried with splitting the string by `/` and taking the first / last character of the splitted string, but im trying to make it more simple.

```
for i in string.gmatch(example, "/") do
   print(i)
end
```

I've also tried:

```
s = "bis 0/5 nta"
a,b = s:match("(.+)/(.+)")
```

Is there some way to get the `0/5` from `bis 0/5 nta`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the parenthesis. Without them, the entire pattern will become the match.
You just need to be more specific with your pattern.

```
str = "bis 0/5 nta"
x = str:match('%d+/%d+') --%d+ means match one or more digits
print(x) --0/5
```

If you're only ever going to be looking for matches like 1/2 or 100/253 this will work. If you have more specific needs put them in a comment and I'll help you work on the pattern.